# Is there a way to push to more than one remote Git branch at the same time?

Tags: git, git-push

In my local repo's `.git/config` I have

```
[remote "public"]
        url = https://github.com/rax/somerepo.git
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/public/*
[branch "master"]
        remote = public
        merge = refs/heads/master
[remote "amazon"]
        url = ssh://ubuntu@ecXXXXXXXXX.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/home/ubuntu/somebarerepo.git
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/amazon/*
[remote "all"]
        url = https://github.com/rax/somerepo.git
        url = ssh://ubuntu@ecXXXXXXXXX.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/home/ubuntu/somebarerepo.git
```

and when I `git push all` I successfully push the latest commit to both the `amazon` and `public` remotes; but the remote branches don't track. For example, if `public` is behind when I push, even though the content there is now up to date, the branch is still indicated as behind.

Is there a way to push to more than one remote branch at the same time?

Comment: Generally, no, you can add a `git fetch --all` afterwards though.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that you can do it.

**BUT** form git version 2.0 the default behavior  has changed so you will have to set the 'push.default' to the desired value (matching in your case)

---

Here is the git v2.0 release notes which explain the change in the way git treat push (simple vs matching). This was updated in git v2.0 to fix the default `git push` behavior.

Prior to git v2.0 when you executed `git push` it would have pushed all your changed branches (**all** and not only the current branch).

> ## Git v2.0 Release Notes
>
> ### Backward compatibility notes
>
> When `git push [$there]` does not say what to push, we have used the
>   traditional **`matching`** semantics so far (all your branches were sent
>   to the remote as long as there already are branches of the same name
>   over there).  In Git 2.0, the default is now the `simple` semantics,
>   which pushes:
>
> - only the current branch to the branch with the same name, and only
>     when the current branch is set to integrate with that remote
>     branch, if you are pushing to the same remote as you fetch from; or
> - only the current branch to the branch with the same name, if you
>     are pushing to a remote that is not where you usually fetch from.
>
> You can use the configuration variable `push.default` to change
>   this.  If you are an old-timer who wants to keep using the
>   `matching` semantics, you can set the variable to `matching`, for
>   example.  Read the documentation for other possibilities.**strong text**